# PrincipalSearchResult<T> with PrincipalSearcher FindAll, why does T have to be Principal and not UserPrincipal

Tags: c#, directoryservices

I'm just curious:

```
List<string> ADUsers = new List<string>();
using (PrincipalContext principle_context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MYDOMAIN"))
using (UserPrincipal user_principal = new UserPrincipal(principle_context) { Enabled = true, Name = "*", EmailAddress = "*" })
using (PrincipalSearcher user_searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(user_principal))
using (PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = user_searcher.FindAll())
{
    foreach (Principal p in results)
    {
        ADUsers.Add(p.Name + " " + ((UserPrincipal)p).EmailAddress);
    }
}
```

...is there a way to avoid having to cast my results here?  I wanted to do something like:

```
using (PrincipalSearchResult<UserPrincipal> results = user_searcher.FindAll())
```

...so that my search result would be of the type I needed it, but it seems the FindAll method only allows using the `<Principal>` type.  Is there a better way?

Thank you.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I also would like to add a direct answer to the question title: Because `T` can be either a `UserPrincipal`, `ComputerPrincipal`, or a `GroupPrincipal`. In your case you may know it will just return `UserPrincipal` objects, but the `PrincipalSearcher` can't statically know that.

Comment: Upvoted because the way the question was set up helped me to quickly implement AD query :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually `foreach` will cast the enumerated values for you so you could do this

```
foreach (UserPrincipal p in results)
{
    ADUsers.Add(p.Name + " " + p.EmailAddress);
}
```

assuming that `Name` is defined within `UserPrincipal` as well as `Principal`.

Comment: Ah, so simple.  That was it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You could try adding a `Cast`.  Change

```
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = user_searcher.FindAll()
```

to

```
var results = user_searcher.FindAll().Cast<UserPrincipal>()
```