# Pass PrincipalSearchResult object to list in ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

My goal is to have a user search AD for existing users based on certain criteria (first name, last name, ID) and display items that match.

I'm using the PrincipalSearcher to accomplish this:

Controller:

```
public ViewResult Index(string fname, string lname, int id)
    {
        UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(pcontext);

        user.GivenName = fname;
        user.Surname = lname;
        user.EmployeeId = id.ToString();

        PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher();
        ps.QueryFilter = user;
        PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = ps.FindAll();

        List<Principal> userResults = new List<Principal>();
        foreach (Principal item in results)
        {
            userResults.Add(item);
        }

        var viewModel = new UserSearchViewModel
        {
            Users = userResults.ToList()
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

At the end i pass the results to the viewmodel that I created, binding it to a list Model.

ViewModel:

```
    public class UserSearchViewModel
{
    public Request Request { get; set; }

    public List<UserSearch> Users { get; set; }

    public int id { get; set; }

    public string fname { get; set; }

    public string lname { get; set; }
}
```

The current error message that I get is the following:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

I have tried changing the userResults to a List type but the error remains. I tried just returning the results but then I can't figure out how to submit the user results and then display the results in the View.

Any help or direction towards accomplishing my goal would be appreciated.

EDIT: Model

```
    public class UserSearch
{
    public int employeeId { get; set; }

    public string firstname { get; set; }

    public string lastname { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `UserSearch` type is yours, right? Can you show it?

Comment: @octavioccl - I have added the model, pretty basic really.

Comment: Yes, then you need to project the `userresult` collection, let me add an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to project userresult to your `UserSearch` model:

```
    var viewModel = new UserSearchViewModel
    {
        Users = ps.FindAll().Cast<UserPrincipal>() // You could use also .OfType<UserPrincipal> 
                            .Select(p=>new UserSearch{employeeid=p.EmployeeId,
                                                      firstname=p.GivenName, 
                                                      lastname=p.SurName})
                            .ToList()
    };
```

With a little help of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26679819/principalsearchresultt-with-principalsearcher-findall-why-does-t-have-to-be-p). `Principal` doesn't have givenname and surname, that's why I do the casting

Comment: I made the change to UserPrincipal instead of Principal but I then get an error message on ps.FindAll():`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalSearchResult<System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal>' to 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalSearchResult<System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal>'`